# Add user as web-admin CentOS Linux 7

Tags: ssh, ftp, useradd

First of all, I'm a newwbie on Linux and CentOS.
My webserver is on CentOS Linux 7 and different sites/domains under:

- `/home/username/www/site1`
- `/home/username/www/site2`

Where "username" is my username in the system. I can connect to the server both via SSH and FTP. This is a virtual server from my provider.

Groups available are `apache` and `wheel`; my account is a member of `apache` and `wheel`.

How do I add a new user (for a developer) so he can connect through SSH and FTP and have the same rights as me (and reach `/home/username/www/`)?

Comment: How about adding a group `developer`? Then make your `/home/username/www` folder available to the group `developer`?

Comment: Yes that was my solution too. But what about adding the user to the "wheel" group?

Comment: I'm not familiar to the `wheel` group, but it seems to own a great lot of files, many of which are created under `root` user. I therefore assume that it has very high privilege. If that's true, it may be risky to grant your developers such a privilege.